# meaning of "what that" and "be like to endure"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

> One can only imagine what that must be like to endure.

It is a script of Harry potter and the prisoner of Azkaban. and the whole sentence is, A dementor's kiss. One can only imagine what that must be like to endure.

I've studied that "what" is abbreviation of "the thing which (that)".

Then in this sentence, "what that" is "(the thing which->)what + that "?

I'm confused about the usage of "that" in this situation.

And I want to know about "be like to endure" .

I've searched it in dictionary, but I can't find proper definition.

Is there a meaning of "to endure"?

Comment: Please give us the source of this sentence and, if possible, a link to the text. Thank you.

Comment: It is a script of Harry potter and the prisoner of Azkaban. and the whole sentence is, A dementor's kiss. One can only imagine what that must be like to endure.

Comment: _What_ doesn't always mean _the thing which_. _What it must be like_ means _how it must be_. Your sentence could be expressed as "One can only imagine what it must be like to endure that." You should look up _endure_ in the dictionary.

Comment: I don't normally take issue with Rowling's phrasing, but I don't like this one (I'd much prefer *One can only imagine what **it** must be like to endure **that***). Same as *I wonder what he would be like to meet*, which I'd rather see as *I wonder what **it** would be like to meet **him***. Except that with the ***endure*** one, ***that*** is probably superfluous (because ***it*** can be seen as referring back to "a dementor's kiss" anyway), but we can't discard ***him*** in my ***meet*** example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *that* here refers to something that is not in this sentence.  This sentence must be part of a larger discussion, and the *that* is what is being discussed.  Thus, the listener will know what the word *that* means in this sentence.

To *be like* something is to *be similar* to it.  For example, jogging is like running.

*Endure* is to "go through" something, or experience something.  To have it happen to you.

So the sentence expresses that the speaker is wondering what someone else felt like as they experienced some event that is being talked about.  Perhaps the speaker is talking about his friend who ran in a marathon, and the speaker has never done that.